# Query using ORDER BY for sorting values in endpoint

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpql

I've taken on advice from posts on this site regarding my issue however I don't believe I'm going in the right direction. The issue I'm striving to solve is providing a sorting method using jpql, which can be demonstrated using this table:

```
 Name | Address | City |
--------------------------
   A  |    A    |   C  | 
   C  |    B    |   B  |
   B  |    C    |   A  |
```

I would like it so that when I pass in the name of a column, I will be able to order by the column for the results of all rows. So for example, if I were to order by name, then it should return A B C not A C B.

The goal I'm trying is that when I pass in a parameter for my API so:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/person?sorting=city
```

Now I understand that this could be resolved using:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/person?sort=city,asc
```

However I am unable to use the sort paramemter for this case, since I am relying on information from multiple domains. So from that I decided to see if it's possible to create a query in my repository that could be used to sort the values. This is my attempt at it so far:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM DePerson p, DeClass c, DeSchool s" +
        "WHERE p.personId = c.id " +
        "AND su.schoolId = s.id " +
        "ORDER BY :ordering")
List<DePerson> sortingAll(String sorting);
```

With that, I'm trying to see if then I am able to pass in this query from my repository and use it in my service method as a sorting method for the results I have when passing the endpoint:

```
    List<PersonDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Page<DePerson> page;

    List<DePerson> personList = page.getContent();
        for (DePerson person: personList) {
            result.add(convertDTO(person));
        }        

    return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, page.getTotalElements());
```

To conclude, I'm trying to create a custom sort parameter using jpql which should be apply to the results when the endpoint is called.

Comment: So what happens when you run it? does it give error ?

Comment: Hello @ShubhamSrivastava it doesn't since not too sure how it would be linked.

Comment: This is not a good idea to pass the sorting into sql directly. You may got security issues like SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic queries it's recommended to use criteria API so to achieve your goal you can do this.

First add an implementation to your PersonRepository and autowired Entity Manager to have something like that

```
PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepository{
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;
    //here you can also pass Page object and modify some staff
    private List<Person> getEntitiesOrder(String sortColumn){
          CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
          Root<Person> people= query.from(Person.class);
          query.select(people).orderBy(cb.desc(people.get(sortColumn)));
          TypedQuery<Person> queryPeople = 
                 entityManager.createQuery(query);
         return queryPeople.getResultList();
    } 
}
```

then form your service or controller you can autowired this repository and you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: Also check this link https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-order-by-clause-criteriaquery/

Comment: Hello, is there anyway I could link this method with my stuff to get it working?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer, check it, and if there is anything not clear tell me.